# What is the difference? clang++ | clang -std=c++11

Tags: c++, c, c++11, clang, clang++

I had been erroneously using this command, which failed at the link step:

`$ clang -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ myInputFile.cpp`

**Can anyone explain why clang provides a C++ language option, and why it fails to link?** Why don't the options `-x c++` or `-std=c++11` accomplish the same thing as `clang++`? Thanks!

Comment: What's up with the downvotes? Yes, I understand that clang++ is just a link to configure clang for C++. That's not my question, please look again. If it's *so* simple please just answer rather than downvote.

Comment: This question in its 4th revision is a perfectly valid question that I do not see any reason to vote to close or to downvote. It is a “Why…?” question but its scope is small enough that there is hope a generally agreed-on rationale will be offered as an answer.

Comment: Should `std=c++11 stdlib=libc++` in the question be `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`?

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to link? Are you linking with the command in the question or a different command?

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are correct; that's what I get for not copy/pasting. I've edited the question one last time to reflect that.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Technically, neither of the programs named `clang` or `clang++` is a compiler: they are both *drivers* that analyze the input arguments and determine what compilers/assemblers/linkers to invoke on what files with what command line arguments. The only difference between the two is that `clang` links against only the C standard library if it performs a link, whereas `clang++` links against both the C++ and C standard libraries.

The `-x=<language>` option overrides the driver programs' heuristics for determining source file language, it directs the driver to invoke the compiler for `<language>` regardless.

The `-std=<dialect>` option picks which dialect of a particular language you want to use. If you need to ensure that your C++ program is portable to an old C++98 compiler, you can compile it with `-std=c++98`. `-std` only applies to the target language: it won't try to compile e.g. assembler or java as C++98, only source files that the driver believes to be C++.

In short, there are two different driver programs to make it easy to select which libraries to link against. There are reasonable use cases for compiling C++ but not linking against the C++ standard library.

Comment: It is similar to gcc vs g++, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Clang is the name of the whole compiler.

However, from a command-line point of view:

- Clang is the C compiler
- Clang++ is the C++ compiler (like g++ is a C++ compiler, whereas gcc is a C compiler)

The -std=c++11 option enables the new C++11 standard (as in g++).

Comment: But, why offer a C++ option flag with the C compiler? That's my main question.

Comment: To remain compatible with the way `gcc` does things.

Comment: @djwbrown: `clang` will likely figure out when it runs on C++ code and successfully produce an object file. The difference between `clang` and `clang++` shows up when it tries to link your object files where C++ requires a different set than C. `clang` will try to link C, and `clang++` C++ code.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier that helps, but why bother giving you the -x or -std= flags if they don't change the linker to the correct language as well?