# How to solve " a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition."

Tags: c++, clang, virtual-functions

I was trying to see how virtual functions are compiled and it seem I cannot compile a trivial example to a dylib on macOS.

I've been through countless permutations of this code and SO answers but I cannot get this trivial example compile (or rather link) with:

```
clang -dynamiclib -o test.dylib test.cc
```

here is the code:

```
class Animal {
    public:
        virtual void who(){};
};

class Cat : Animal
{
  public:
    virtual void who();
};

void Cat::who() {
    }
```

and here is the complete error:

```
clang -dynamiclib -o test.dylib test.cc
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Animal in test-be905f.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Cat in test-be905f.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Use clang++, not clang.

Comment: Wow, just wow. I worked. Could you elaborate a bit and explain why the other one works and the other one doesn't as they both compile C++ ? If

Comment: This StackOverflow question may help you: [What is the difference? clang++ | clang -std=c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20047218/12149471)

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. But I have to agree with one of the commenters:" but why bother giving you the -x or -std= flags if they don't change the linker to the correct language as well?" ie if it looks like it understands that the code is c++ and it compiles it, why does it not go all the way ...

Comment: It's possible to write C++ without using the standard library (this is called "barebones" or "freestanding" C++). For example, you might want to use C++ internally within a file used in a C program or kernel module, and in that case it would not be desirable to pull in the C++ standard library.

Comment: @ecatmur I see, thanks. Still I can't help feeling that someone could have made better job on the error message or the way to invoke this feature to do "barebones" C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NOTE` is a red herring, I'm afraid. `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info` is a symbol in the C++ standard library, not in your code (`std::type_info` is a [polymorphic class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/%7Etype_info)), so this error actually means that you need to link against the C++ standard library.

The simplest way to do this is to change `clang` to `clang++` in the command line you've written. The [difference between `clang` and `clang++`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047218/what-is-the-difference-clang-clang-std-c11?noredirect=1&lq=1) is that the former defaults to compiling and linking as C, while the latter defaults to compiling and linking C++, but each are capable of *compiling* both languages.